# Function Doesn't Execute When Passed to Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a functional component which I pass a function `addEvent` to, which takes an event parameter. However, when I call the function from props inside a functional component, the function doesn't execute:

```
const onOk = () => {
  const { title, description, start_time, end_time, remind_time } = formStates;
  const event = { 
    title:title[0], 
    description:description[0], 
    start_time:start_time.toISOString(),
    end_time: end_time.toISOString(),
    remind_time: remind_time.toISOString()
  }
  props.addEvent(event);
  props.hideModal();
};

const ModalConductor = props => {
switch(props.modal.currentModal) {
    case EVENT_FORM_MODAL:
        return <EventsFormModal {...props} title="New Event" addEvent={addEvent}/> 

    default:
        return null;
}
};
```

Passed Function:

```
export const addEvent = (event) => dispatch => {
console.log(event);
axios
    .post('/api/events/', event)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_EVENT,
            payload: res.data
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I have read on React docs that passing functions to components requires a `this.function = this.function.bind(this);`. However, there is no `this` in a functional component and there is no example in the docs. How would I fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code ModalConductor is your functional component which takes props as input.
you are accessing addEvent directly, instead of props.addEvent.

```
const ModalConductor = props => {
switch(props.modal.currentModal) {
    case EVENT_FORM_MODAL:
        return <EventsFormModal {...props} title="New Event" addEvent={props.addEvent}/> 

    default:
        return null;
}
};
```

also as long as your function definition doesn't contain 'this', you dont have to worry about 'this' binding.